# 2 possible value for queries in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

```
<tr>
    <td>Search Role  :</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtsearchrole" name="txtsearchrole" value="" class="box required"/>
    </td>
    <td>Role Id  :</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="roleid" class="box required"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this is my select statement

```
function RetrieveRole(){
    global $dbh;
    //$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM rolelist WHERE rolelist_id IN (1,2) ");
    if (!empty($_GET['rolename'])) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM rolelist WHERE role_name LIKE ?") ;
        $stmt->bindValue(1,"%".$_GET['rolename']."%");
        if($stmt->execute()){
            if($stmt -> rowCount() >0){
            $role_name = array();
                while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $role_name[] = array('rolename'  => $selected_row['role_name'],'roleid'  => $selected_row['rolelist_id']);
                }
            return  $role_name;

            }else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Role found');
                window.location='../pages/dashboard.php';
                </script>";
                exit;
            }           
        }           
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Search Role Name is Blank');
        window.location='../pages/dashboard.php';
        </script>";
        exit;
    }       
}
```

This is a code im using to search or select query using role name i was able to usefully make it work i get results now i added the `Role Id` in it so that the user can either search using the name or role id i am searching on how to make this possible but unfortunately i cant find the exact answer to this problem if anyone has source or suggestion please do so i appreciate any suggestion or idea

Comment: Rather than redirecting using javascript, you should use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php. `header('Location: pages/dashboard.php');`

Comment: Your HTML has txtsearchrole and roleid but your are using $_GET['rolename'[

Comment: i am asking on the select part @jeff i found something maybe it can solve my problem it i should use or in the select statement i will give it a try

Comment: @iswinky i want to show an alert text so i am using javascript is there a way to show alert message in php without using javascript?

Comment: @HogRider you could just return an array of messages and loop through them on the page. `return array ("error"=>"No roles found");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must change if statement

```
if (isset($_GET['txtsearchrole']) || isset($_GET['roleid'])) {
```

then you must change your query to include search for role id too:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM rolelist WHERE role_name LIKE ? OR role_id  = ?") ;
```

then change your bind parameters section :

```
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['txtsearchrole'], $_GET['roleid']));
```

Comment: in your question the form element name property of `input` text used for `rolename` is `txtsearchrole`.

Comment: sorry about that i made a mistake i used the one i commented but nonetheless the code work perfectly thanks for the suggestion/answer

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['rolename'] || $_GET['roleid'])) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM rolelist WHERE role_name LIKE ? OR role_id = ?") ;
        $stmt->execute(array($_GET['txtsearchrole'], $_GET['roleid']));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: note that , name of input text that used for rolename is `txtsearchrole`